# button action depending on the section that is visible

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

Beginner here ... I usually try to find solutions here but I didn't find one at the moment. I have a single-page website with multiple sections. I have implemented a switch visible function that shows a single section while hiding the others. Now each section has a bottom bar that I want to make dynamic but **the bar has also a button**. I want a button whose onclick action changes depending on the section that is visible. So how can I do that?

Here's my switchfunction

```
function switchVisible() {
    if (document.getElementById('Div1')) {

        if (document.getElementById('Div1').style.display == 'none') {
            document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}
```

and the bottom bar

```
<div class="row bottom-bar height-3 justify-content-between">
     <div class="col-4">
        <p>Meal Type: Keto</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-4">
        <p>Starting From: 550 SAR</p>
     </div>
     <div id="orange-button" class="col-4 orange">
         <p>
           <input id="Button1" type="button" class="continue-btn" value="Continue" onclick="switchVisible2();" />
           </p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, detecting or toggling visibility of element using its `style.display == 'block'` or `'none'` isn't a good idea. For the exact reason that other buttons need this info so they should also check `style.display` of a different element and that is cumbersome. A better approach is using a `css` class which is a little more clean: you can add, remove, initialize or check if exists a class on element rather easily.

```js
var div1 = document.getElementById('Div1')
var div2 = document.getElementById('Div2')

function switchVisible() {
  if (div1.classList.contains("my-hidden")) {
    div1.classList.remove("my-hidden");
    div2.classList.add("my-hidden");
  } else {
    div1.classList.add("my-hidden");
    div2.classList.remove("my-hidden");
  }
}

function switchVisible2() {
  if (!div1.classList.contains("my-hidden")) {
    console.log("div1 action");
  }
  if (!div2.classList.contains("my-hidden")) {
    console.log("div2 action");
  }
}
```

```css
.my-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="Div1">Div1</div>
<div id="Div2" class="my-hidden">Div2</div>

<button onclick="switchVisible()">switchVisible</button>

<div class="row bottom-bar height-3 justify-content-between">
  <div class="col-4">
    <p>Meal Type: Keto</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <p>Starting From: 550 SAR</p>
  </div>
  <div id="orange-button" class="col-4 orange">
    <p>
      <input id="Button1" type="button" class="continue-btn" value="Continue" onclick="switchVisible2();" />
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```